# C# how to open two windows and make one control certain variables

Tags: c#

Okay so I'm going to try my best to explain this. Me and a group of my friends are running a streaming event and as a little extra thing for the viewers we decided to have our own custom C# game running in the stream.

Here is my issue, we want a form box of some sort in a separate window so we can move it too a second monitor. We want it on a second monitor because we are capturing an entire screen and we don't want them (the viewers) to ever see the form box.

We need this form to be able to control certain variables that trigger events within the game to add the illusion of an AI. The reason I don't just make an AI is because we want it to do different things based on the viewers which we have no control over. Is there anyway at all to achieve this in C#?

Comment: How much C# experience do you have? This could be anything from trivially easy to dreadfully difficult depending on how much coding you've done.  Also what GUI toolkit are you using? (Winforms, WPF, an alternative?) You'll need to be more specific (and perhaps eliminate the additional explanation) to get a good answer.

Comment: You asking if you can create two forms, and have one access methods on the other? Does that boil it down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you created a class that represented your view (like a ViewModel).  And it implemented INotifyPropertyChanged... you could create a public static instance (probably a singleton) that you could bind both forms to.  If your properties are created like this:

```
    private string _Message;
    public string Message
    {
        get { return _Message; }
        set
        {
            _Message = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Message"));
        }
    }
```

both of the forms should be notified when either form updates a value on the class instance.

THIS IS NOT THREADSAFE!!! But that might not matter.

Comment: It wasn't that bad... I didn't down vote. And you are welcome ;)

Answer (score 0):

In your form1 class create getters and setters for your variables, then call them from your form2 class.

```
public int value;

public void setValue(int val){
this.value = val;
}
public int getValue{
return this.value;
}
```